# Message "Failed to instantiate module growlNotifications..." appear on production env

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, bower, mean-stack

I am current using mean.io as development framework of my application and have been using growlNotifications plug-in for certain time and it works perfect on both server and client side.

while after some coding commit (does not affect the plug-in), the following error appear on the production server:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module acleague due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module growlNotifications due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'growlNotifications' is not available! You either...<omitted>...3)
```

but it won't have any problem running on local. I ensure that the bower install work perfectly on production server and i did nth in the grunt file.

Could anyone help me or even give me some hints to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was set the bower component as latest, the production server will run the bower update command to get the latest one while local does not.

So I upgraded the plugin and run it on both sides, it works now.